# How to Have Device Encryption With Magisk Systemless Root Installed?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption, systemless-root, magisk

I am currently owning a **OnePlus 3 64 GB** device rooted with **Magisk v13.0 (96f8efc) and MagiskSU's systemless root**, and using the following ROM, which is based of **Android 7.1.2 (Lieanage OS)**: **Resurrection Remix OS (version: RR-N-v5.8.3-20170624-oneplus3-Unofficial)**, and the build number is: **Resurrection Remix Nougat 7.1.2_r17-NJH47B**.

I have tried the encryption setting, but it didn't (possibly) go well, as I ended up having short (possibly) 30 seconds soft restarts with my phone after the encryption process completes, and the only way to end this soft bootloop was to do one hard reboot. I also saw some missing apps (such as Maps) after the (faulty) encryption process. Furthermore, and this is the most important and annoying thing I found, is that once I set a password/pattern/pin after the encryption, and add the option to require it after booting, it will not be changed later, even if I changed it later on and added the same option of requiring it on reboot, the first would still persist.

I would like to know if there are steps (and possibly better ROM suggestions) that I could do to achieve full security using device encryption, while still benefiting from Magisk's systemless root that has the option of Magisk hide (using MagiskSu)?

I don't want to expose my data to thieves, as booting into recovery mode would show all my personal information as if I am running the device on root, and with that, you can easily wipe the lockscreen password by deleting the password database.

Really appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: I think TWRP can access your data even if encrypted... There is no way to maintain device security when you have unlocked bootloader, and you can't relock the bootloader if rooted or running a custom ROM in modern devices to my knowledge. For true security you must go back to pure stock and lock your bootloader.

Comment: In TWRP, I cannot access my files unless I provide the decryption password, that's why I want to know if such device decryption is possible without losing root possibilities and root hide!!

Comment: Fair enough... I am more used to dealing with adopted storage encryption which must be handled differently with TWRP.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This was an old problem with Lineage OS based ROMS, where the encryption just didn't work properly. The problem is that ones the encryption is set, it cannot be changed in the GUI. However, I had a success in the past where I changed my encryption key through `vdc cryptfs changepw` command that can be run on the `Terminal` app from the developer menu (or any terminal emulator) with a required root access, and you can only change an old password to a new password, an old pattern to a new pattern, ...etc, but not a pattern to a password, ...etc.

I believe the issue has been resolved in the latest Lineage OS (correct me if I am wrong), as I am using another Lineage OS dialect called Havoc OS that have this issue perfectly resolved!